# How to structure a .json file for php

Tags: php, json, web-testing

I have this php code that acesses a json file. The json file however is empty and I need to put in an example value. However, I can't seem to structure it correctly. The code:

```
<?php
     $strJsonFileContents = file_get_contents("../private/storage/device_list.json");
     $victim_array = json_decode($strJsonFileContents, true);
     $index_victim = 1;

     foreach ($victim_array["device_list"] as $field => $value) {

     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>'.$index_victim.'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.strtoupper($value['DEVICE_MODEL']).'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$value['SOFTWARE_VERSION'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$value['COUNTRY'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$value['SIM_OPERATOR'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$value['CHARGE'].'</td>';
     echo '<td>'.$value['IS_ROOTED'].'</td>';
     echo '<td><a href="kontrol-panel.php?target='.$value['UNIQUE_ID'].'&type=1'.'">Attack</a></td>';
     echo '</tr>';
     $index_victim += 1;
     }
?>
```

Here is the structure of the json I have been trying.

```
{
    "device_list": {
        "device1": {
            "DEVICE_MODEL": "Test",
            "SOFTWARE_VERSION": "Test",
            "COUNTRY": "Test",
            "SIM_OPERATOR": "Test",
            "CHARGE": "Test",
            "IS_ROOTED": "Test",
            "UNIQUE_ID": "Test"
        }
    }
}
```

That returns the eror

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in C:\Server\Data\htdocs\hidden\public\index.php:87 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Server\Data\htdocs\hidden\public\index.php on line 87
```

Lines that concern line 87:

```
echo '<tr>';
                                echo '<td>'.$index_victim.'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.strtoupper($value['DEVICE_MODEL']).'</td>'; (line 87)
                                echo '<td>'.$value['SOFTWARE_VERSION'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$value['COUNTRY'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$value['SIM_OPERATOR'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$value['CHARGE'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td>'.$value['IS_ROOTED'].'</td>';
                                echo '<td><a href="kontrol-panel.php?target='.$value['UNIQUE_ID'].'&type=1'.'">Attack</a></td>';
                                echo '</tr>';
                                $index_victim += 1;
```

How can I correct structure the json file?

Comment: Always worth checking your JSON is valid - `"UNIQUE_ID": "Test",` shouldn't have a comma at the end.

Comment: Lots of JSON Linters out there

Comment: What are Linters

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software): "_Lint, or a linter, is a static code analysis tool used to flag programming errors, bugs, stylistic errors and suspicious constructs._"

Comment: redid question.

Comment: "_redid question_" Which would make it a new question, but anyway: are you aware of your JSON structure? Where's `device1` in your code?

Comment: Also, you're trying to iterate a structure that isn't an array. And @brombeer's point is a good one.

Comment: "device_list" is not an array, it is a property of the JSON object. Let's say you want to point the 'IS_ROOTED' element/property, you need to address it like '$victim_array ->device_list->device1->IS_ROOTED'

Comment: @BrokenArrow They are passing "true" to json_decode, which makes all objects arrays. Their code is valid for that bit.

Comment: Look I have absolutely no idea how to use and structure json. This is a small part of a big project. Can someone please answer or comment with a fix for the json or the php?

Comment: @Kyle Ahh ha... My bad I missed that part! Thanks mate.

Comment: @ZVH1 The code you provided is 100% correct and does not produce any errors when run. Please provide a minimum code sample that can reproduce the issue you are seeing. See code working here: https://paiza.io/projects/i7TOwsDox4iWfClSQSHSVg

Comment: It is part of a self hosted website. Lemme send a zip of the code.

Comment: The code ran perfectly for me with that JSON. Are you sure you are using the same JSON as you posted here?

Comment: The error description clearly indicates the 'device1' node is either a string from the input JSON, or being altered/set to string before line#87

Comment: Got the code from here. https://github.com/emreakcadag/RaptorWebPanel It’s part of a larger project but this portion runs by itself.

Comment: Thank you all so so so much. I am a massive idiot and forgot to save the changes to the json. You all are really helpful. Thanks you much :).